# When using SSH to connect to Pi2, I think I have problem with Permissions

Tags: ssh, putty

Here is my situation.

I use Putty to make an SSH connection from Windows 10 to my Raspberry Pi2 (running latest Raspbian).

If I use just my standard Password to login, everything works fine.

If I use a Public/Private key-pair (with the Putty key generator and Pageant) I have a problem.

I store the public key (as one line) on raspberry in;

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However I cannot login via Putty, I get a failed authentication.

If however, I move the `authorized_keys` file (where the public key is stored) to: `/etc/ssh/Username/authorized_keys` and I edit my `sshd_config` file to retrieve the key from there - everything works fine!

So, as I see it, I have some sort of permission problem in the folder `~/.ssh`, which causes the `authorized_keys` file to be unavailable.

I have 2 questions;

1. Is it safe if I leave my public key `authorized_keys` in the
   `/etc/ssh/Username/` folder?
2. If it is not safe, what should I do?

Edit;

Here is what I get when I use  `ls -la` on my folder `~/.ssh` ;

```
total 12
drwx------  2 MyPi MyPi 4096 Dec 21 16:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 MyPi MyPi 4096 Dec 21 17:25 ..
-rw-------  1 MyPi MyPi  398 Dec 21 16:54 authorized_keys
```

Comment: What where the permissions of the key file and the folder? http://superuser.com/q/215504/365077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a public key you are copying to the Pi you can leave it in `/etc/ssh/username` folder. The public key can be shared freely and does not present a security issue - this is not true for the private key which should never be shared with anyone. However, it would be better to figure out what is wrong with your current configuration.

You mention possible permissions issues, but you do not mention what the permissions are on the `/home/pi/.ssh` (assuming you are trying to login as `pi`) and the `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` files. They should be `700` (i.e. `drwx------`) and `600` (i.e. `-rw-------`) respectively. You can verify this with the `ls -la` command. If the permission is wrong you can change it with `chmod 700 /home/pi/.ssh`.

In addition they should both have the owner and group set to `pi` (again assuming that is the user your are trying to login as). You can verify this with the `ls -la` command as well `ls -la /home/pi/` and `ls -la /home/pi/.ssh/` respectively.

I wrote a post on [setting up passwordless logins from Windows](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148032481829/ssh-security-and-usability-part-1) for our blog.

Comment: Additionally it might be worth mentioning that the private id files which the `man` page for `ssh` mentions could be: `~/.ssh/identity`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, and/or `~/.ssh/id_rsa` __MUST__ have no permissions for group or other persons otherwise `ssh` will simply ignore them.

Comment: @SlySven good point, but those are not on the Pi

Comment: Here is what I get when I use ` ls -la` on my folder ` ~/.ssh ` ;
`total 12

drwx------  2 MyUserPiName MyUserPiName 4096 Dec 21 16:40 .

drwxr-xr-x 29 MyUserPiName MyUserPiName 4096 Dec 21 17:25 ..
-rw-------  1 MyUserPiName MyUserPiName  398 Dec 21 16:54 authorized_keys`

Comment: @Ivan_Grozny DO NOT post detail into Comments. Edit into your question.